# How reliable are GCP beta services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm planning to use GCP Firestore with Cloud Functions. The cloud functions trigger for firestore is still in Beta.
How reliable is it really to use it in production? It's been in beta since past 1.5 years.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [Public Google Cloud Platform documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore) the beta products have limited support and no SLA.

This doesn't mean that you can't use them in your production environment. If you did a good testing in your dev environment and the behaviour of the product is the expected using a beta product may be safe. But you need to keep in mind that changes may be applied without backward compatibility and this means that you application may be broken from one day to another. Even more important, since there is no deprecation policy for a beta product a beta feature can be removed suddenly, so an important thing to keep in mind.

So if you are able to keep track of futures changes and a major changes on this particular feature won't mean that you entire application will be down is safe to go ahead and include this in your production env, otherwise if this will be part of a critical feature of your product I will recommend you to wait